# Using LIKE in a stored procedure and escaping injection at same time

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, escaping, code-injection

So I have a stored procedure in MySQL

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mysearch;

CREATE PROCEDURE mysearch (IN term varchar(255), IN brands varchar(512), IN categories varchar(512), IN priceRange varchar(32))
BEGIN
  SET @query = 'SELECT name, price, image FROM (... join some tables here ... ) WHERE (... prod.category = some number ...)';

  IF (term IS NOT NULL) THEN
    SET term = CONCAT('\'%',term,'%\'');
    SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' AND (prod.name LIKE ', QUOTE(term), ' OR prod.number LIKE ', QUOTE(term), ')');
  END IF;
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;

  EXECUTE stmt1;
END //
delimiter ;
```

How can I use LIKE and still escape user input?

I would like to sanitize user input, but still allow search using LIKE.

Comment: You are missing the `WHERE`..

Comment: I know, I omitted that as I thought that the main question was about how to use LIKE and escape, rather than throw in where

Comment: ok. was just making sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mysearch;

CREATE PROCEDURE mysearch (IN term varchar(255), IN brands varchar(512), IN categories varchar(512), IN priceRange varchar(32))
BEGIN
  DECLARE fullterm varchar(255);
  SET fullterm = CONCAT('%',term,'%');

  SELECT name, price, image FROM (... join some tables here ... ) WHERE (... prod.category = some number ...)
  AND (term IS NULL OR (prod.name LIKE fullterm OR prod.number LIKE fullterm));
END
```

**Demo at** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5e50/9

Comment: I really love this example, especially with the fiddle, but can you tell me, how is it that this escapes injection? (I'm connecting from JDBC to my database and users can enter a single quote as part of a search term, would this not allow injection?

Comment: @EliteOctagon, injection occurs when you ***execute*** input from the user. Since the query is not dynamic (*it is not created from a concatenated string*)  and the input of the user just stays in a variable and is only used for testing against, it is handled by the DB engine correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using [PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) statement. 
There is an example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/how-to-use-prepared-statements-within-mysql-stored-procedures).